# How to avoid breaking Liskov substitution principle when overriding method signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, mypy, liskov-substitution-principle

I have an abstract class `DataWriter` that defines an abstract method `write()`. This class is supposed to be the base class for a dynamic set of concrete classes, each one of which is intended to implement its own version of the method `write()`. In order to define the datatype of parameter `meta` of the method `write()`, I created the type **WriterMeta** as follows:

`WriterMeta = typing.Union[GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable]`

Each concrete class would be in charge of processing one of the different types that conform to the union, but linter **mypy** doesn't seem to grasp that, because when I define the signature of the method `write()` of the concrete class using one of the types of the union for parameter `meta`, it marks a `Liskov substituion principle violation`, which I believe doesn't exist because the concret class is a subset of the abstract class, which means that the parent class can substitute the child class with no problem.

This is my code:

```
class LocalWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    file_name: str


class GSheetWritable(typing.TypedDict):
    tab_name: str


class S3Writable(typing.TypedDict):
    data_name: str
    table_name: str


WriterMeta = typing.Union[GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable]

class GSheetOutputWriter(DataWriter):
    def __init__(
        self, google_driver: GoogleApiDriver, folder: str, settings, timestamp, env
    ):
        self._connector = google_driver
        self.folder = folder
        self.settings = settings
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.env = env
        self.file_name = self.get_file_name()
        self._target = self.create_gsheet()
        self.new = True

    def get_file_name(self) -> str:
        file_name = (
            "boxes_shipping_costs_"
            + self.settings["volume_source"]
            + "_"
            + (
                self.timestamp
                if self.settings["volume_source"] == "adhoc"
                else self.settings["scm_week"]
            )
        )

        return file_name

    def create_gsheet(self):
        gsheet = self.connector.sheet_create(self.file_name, folder_id=self.folder)
        gsheet.worksheet("Sheet1").resize(rows=1, cols=1)

        return gsheet

    @property
    def connector(self) -> typing.Any:
        return self._connector

    @property
    def target(self) -> typing.Any:
        return self._target

    def write(self, data: pd.DataFrame, meta: GSheetWritable, versionize: bool):
        data = data.replace({np.nan: 0, np.Inf: "Inf"})

        print("Writing '{}' table to gsheet.".format(meta["tab_name"]))
        if self.new:
            tab = self.connector.get_worksheet(self.target.url, "Sheet1")
            self.connector.rename_worksheet(tab, meta["tab_name"])
            self.new = False
        else:
            tab = self.connector.add_worksheet(
                self.target, meta["tab_name"], rows=1, cols=1
            )

        time.sleep(random.randint(30, 60))
        self.connector.update_worksheet(
            tab, [data.columns.values.tolist()] + data.values.tolist()
        )
```

Is my understanding of Liskov sustitution principle right? How can I refactor this set of classes for **mypy** to accept them?

Comment: Your `meta` parameter is typed as `GSheetWritable`, didn't you mean to type it as `WriterMeta`?

Answer (score 6):

### Why this fails

When you declare abstract class method that operates on some type `T` (`Union` in your case), from mypy point of view it means the following: *every* subclass must implement this method that accepts type `T` or wider. Method, accepting only part of `T`, violates LSP: whenever you refer to abstract class, you suppose that everything of type `T` can be used in the method, while concrete implementation doesn't allow that.

### Type safe way – generic solution

You can use generic classes for that.

```py
import pandas as pd
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, TypedDict

class LocalWritable(TypedDict):
    file_name: str

class GSheetWritable(TypedDict):
    tab_name: str

class S3Writable(TypedDict):
    data_name: str
    table_name: str

# This variable is compatible with any of classes or their subclasses,
# not with `Union` of them as opposed to TypeVar(bound=Union[...]) usage.
_OutputT = TypeVar('_OutputT', GSheetWritable, S3Writable, LocalWritable)

class DataWriter(ABC, Generic[_OutputT]):
    @abstractmethod
    def write(self, data: pd.DataFrame, meta: _OutputT, versionize: bool) -> None: ...

class GSheetDataWriter(DataWriter[GSheetWritable]):
    def write(self, data: pd.DataFrame, meta: GSheetWritable, versionize: bool) -> None:
        pass
        # Implementation goes here
```